# What is the recommended way to access Service Layer by client code in Java web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, model-view-controller, exception, struts-1

I am trying to learn to design LAYERED ARCHITECTURE (presentation layer,service layer and DAO layer) for java web application. I am using Struts 1.3 and also programming to interfaces principle across the Service and DAO layers. What is the recommended way of accessing Service Layer in the ActionMethods of the Struts Action classes? Can the Factory pattern be used to create Service layer objects? If not what could be a better design flow?

Regards,
Shiva

Comment: Have posted [sample code implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104363/layered-architecture-implementation-in-a-java-web-application) of the same concept at codereview site. Kindly suggest solutions for the questions following.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options.

1. Factory pattern: You handle the life cycle of the services. If the factory is not relying on singleton instance then you will end up with many service layer instances or create one each time. This may be ok based on your need. But if your services can be stateless then you are wasting lot of resources.
2. Spring bean injection is another option that widely used. You can wire the actions with service instances using spring. Spring provides various options to manage the life cycle of those instances.
3. You can use a custom service locator.

Your service layer can act as a transaction boundary.

Comment: Hello @Integrator, thanx for replying. Of the 3 options mentioned I do not have knowledge of the Spring framework and Of the remaining 2 options which would be the optimal approach?

Comment: Spring is worth looking at. Else, i prefer the factory approach.

Comment: Hello @Integrator, can the Abstract Factory pattern by GoF be used in this regard?

Comment: If you are using Java EE 6 or higher, Spring is not necessary as CDI has been introduced. Java EE 7 and higher has built CDI containers that does useful injections. Unfortunately Struts 1.x was not designed for CDI. There is a project online called `Struts-CDI` that only injects EJB's.